# Playing a song from the retrieved songs list

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

This is my code for retrieving the list of the songs on the device. I want to play the selected song. Couldn't figure out how to use the onItemClickListener to do it. How do I do that in another activity?

```
public class SongsFragment extends Fragment {


public SongsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false);
    ListView audioView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.songView);
    ArrayList<String> audioList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
    final Cursor audioCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

    if (audioCursor != null) {
        if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

                audioList.add(audioCursor.getString(audioIndex));
            } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    audioCursor.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, audioList);
    audioView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use audioView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object song = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //TODO play song
   } 
});

Basically, when you click a song item from the list view, you will just get the value of the selected song and then you can then play it.